# Special Customized Incremental Column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a table `TableTask` with 3 columns:

```
TaskID, DesignID, TaskName
```

I would like to have `TaskName` a special column which its auto number depending on `DesignID`, and I would like to have repeated `.XXX` portions but each record is still unique because there is `IDX` portion

```
ID1.001, ID1.002, ..., ID1.999
ID2.001, ID2.002
```

I have tried something like what I have in the code below but I can only get

```
ID1.001, ID1.002, ID1.003, ID2.004, ID2.005
```

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE TableTask
(
    TaskID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    DesignID INT NOT NULL,
    TaskName AS 'ID' + CAST(DesignID AS VARCHAR(6)) + '.' +
                       RIGHT('000' + CAST(TaskID AS VARCHAR(3)), 3) PERSISTED
)
```

Comment: am trying to understand in which world this would be useful. Did you try row_number() over (partition by DesignId order by id) ?

Comment: My department is not IT department but I have some IT skills and my boss asked me to develop many apps that may not be the best but they are good for us. Sometimes, the boss just wants to have certain things they may not be useful (to me) but he wants what he wants.  Sometimes, I can argue, sometimes I give up.

Comment: You should never store information like that in the database

Comment: I guess I could handle the presentation at the application side instead of letting the database handle it

Comment: That would be a really good idea

Comment: Do the values need to be as dense as a boss, i.e. will the universe end in division-by-zero if `ID42.666` is followed by `ID42.668` because a transaction was rolled back? I presume they need to be stable, i.e. deleting or updating a row won't cause the `TaskName` for other rows to change. (You _can't_ update a `DesignId`, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that at query time with `row_number` (example with variable for easy testing):

```
declare @TableTask TABLE 
(
    TaskID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    DesignID INT NOT NULL
)

insert into @TableTask values(1), (2), (1), (1), (2), (3), (4)

select *, 
    'ID' + CAST(DesignID AS VARCHAR(6)) + '.' + RIGHT('000' + convert(varchar(3), row_number() over (partition by DesignID order by TaskID)), 3) AS TasName
from @TableTask
```

Output:

```
1   1   ID1.001
3   1   ID1.002
4   1   ID1.003
2   2   ID2.001
5   2   ID2.002
6   3   ID3.001
7   4   ID4.001
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make it a Computed Column that calls a function that returns the next highest .XXX portion for that row's Design ID, and concatenates them.

```
DesignID + '.' + MySchema.MyFunction(DesignID)
```

The code in the function, in simple psuedocode, would look something like this:

```
DECLARE @Output int;

SELECT @Output=CONVERT(int,RIGHT(MAX(TaskName),3))
FROM MyTable
WHERE DesignID=@parameter;

IF @Output IS NULL
  SET @Output=0;

RETURN @Output + 1;
```

This assumes the function returns an integer, and you build the `TaskName` string in the computation.   Alternately you could have the function return a string and do all the string-building there.

Comment: I have a really hard time seeing how this can help

Comment: Why?   It produces exactly what OP asks for.   Treating the question as academic and leaving aside whether there is a better way, this answers the question.

Comment: Ok, now I am curious, what would be the script for this function ?

Comment: It would get the MAX TaskName for the DesignID passed to it, parse it to get the .XXX value, add one to it, and return that numeric value.

Comment: please show me. Because I would not be able to write that function

Comment: that will have to wait til Monday.  It's quitting time here.   :)